# Can't get value from child element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the value of the third `<p>` element by referring to the id of its parent (`id="pickup-searchbox"`), but first I'm referring to the class of the first chid (`class="searchbox-info"`), but the value is empty.

Here is the html code of the page I'm working with and my script.

```
<div class="searchbox-wrapper show-info" id="pickup-searchbox">
   <div class="searchbox-inner-wrapper">
   ......
   </div>
   <div class="searchbox-info" tabindex="-1">
      <p style="font-weight: 400; margin-bottom: 15px;" class="t-text">Пункт получения:</p><p class="t-text">На Станиславского</p>
      <p class="t-text">Адрес: ул. Станиславского, 115А/1</p>
      <p class="t-text" style="opacity: 0.6; line-height: 22px; font-size: .9rem;">По улице Станиславского, между пер. Крыловской и пер. Университетский</p>
      <p class="t-text">Время работы: Пн-Пт 09:00-20:00, Сб-Вс 10:00-19:00</p>
      <p class="t-text">Телефон: +78632631122</p><span style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 10px; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" class="t-text searchbox-change-pickup">Изменить</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#allrecords').change(function() {

    var address = $('#pickup-searchbox').children('.searchbox-info').find('p:nth-child(3)').val(); 

    $('#input_1699283005593').val(address);
    
});
});

</script>
```

I tried accessing the element this way and expected to get the value of the element, but the script can't get it

Comment: The issue with your script is that `.val()` is used to get the value of form elements ´. Since you're trying to get the content of a `<p>` element, you should be using `.text()` instead.

Comment: `.children` only looks in the immediate-children, not "all children" - change to `$('#pickup-searchbox').find('.searchbox-info').find('p:nth-child(3)')` or just `$("#pickup-searchbox p:nth-child(3)")` and not use .children/.find

Comment: As also noted above re `.val()` - make sure you *break down the issue* - there's no point changing `.val()` to `.text()` if your selector is wrong (and, conversely, there's no point fixing the selector and still using `.val()`).  You need to determine each issue *in order* - first, make sure your selector is working by checking it actually selects something - ie `var element = $("#id").find("p:nth-child(3)"); console.log(element.length)` - if your selector is wrong then .length will === 0 - so fix that first.

Comment: Just use html() or text() in place of val()